# The getter 'length' was called on snapshot's data

Tags: firebase, flutter

When the app starts it throws an Exception caught by widgets library in a console:

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library ======================================================= The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building
StreamBuilder<List<Entry>>(dirty, state:
_StreamBuilderBaseState<List<Entry>, AsyncSnapshot<List<Entry>>>#97504): The getter 'length' was called on
null. Receiver: null Tried calling: length on `itemCount: snapshot.data.length`,
```

But the whole app nonetheless works in emulator. What is the reason of that?

```
StreamBuilder<List<Entry>>(
          stream: entryProvider.entries,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length, // the error is here
                itemBuilder: (context, index) { ...
```

Comment: add `print(snapshot.data)` before calling `return ListView.builder(` and you will see that it is `null` - basically you cannot access `length`  property on `null` object

Comment: It seems to say that `snapshot.data` was `null`.

Comment: @pskink at some moment it may be true but as I said the whole app is working and it shows the snapshot's data which are definitely not empty

Comment: sure thats why dart language has `if` / `switch` statements ;-) - you can see the whole example [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) how they build widgets depending on snapshot's state

Comment: ... or you can simply add `initialData: []` to your `StreamBuilder` - i did not test it but it should work

Comment: @pskink initialData works with no issues and another way is to use conditional statement to check snapshot.hasData

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the stream is busy loading data, snapshot.data will be null until the `ConnectionState` of `StreamBuilder` is `ConnectionState.done`.

There are a few fixes you can try.

**1. Use if (snapshot.hasData)**

This will ensure that `snapshot.data` is used only when it is not null

**2. Use Null operator**

When trying to get the length of `snapshot.data`, try this

```
    snapshot?.data.length ?? 0
```

**3. Check `ConnectionState`**

You can also check the `ConnectionState` of StreamBuilder but you might still need to use the first solution i.e, `snapshot.hasData`, normally I
would prefer one of the above solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Use `snapshot.data.size` instead of `.length`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 solved the problem by replacing StreamBuilder<Object> with StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>. by default the StreamBuilder comes in this form StreamBuilder<Object>
```

this will work 100%